# Can you bind the visibility of a GroupBox to the visibility of it's children?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have an issue trying to get a GroupBox to collapse. I want a GroupBox which will collapse if all it's children are collapsed.

I have managed to achieve this using a multibinding to the properties, as shown below.

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <GroupBox>
      <GroupBox.Visibility>
        <MultiBinding 
          Converter="{StaticResource multiBoolOrToVis}"
          ConverterParameter="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"
        >
          <Binding Path="a_visible"/>
          <Binding Path="b_visible"/>
        </MultiBinding>
      </GroupBox.Visibility>
        <GroupBox.Header>
        <Label Content="GroupBox"/>
      </GroupBox.Header>
      <StackPanel>
        <Label 
          Content="A"
          Visibility="{Binding Path=a_visible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}"
        />
        <Label 
          Content="B"
          Visibility="{Binding Path=b_visible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}"
        />
      </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <CheckBox 
        Content="A Visible"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.Row="1"
        IsChecked="{Binding Path=a_visible, Mode=TwoWay}"
      />
      <CheckBox 
        Content="B Visible"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        IsChecked="{Binding Path=b_visible, Mode=TwoWay}"
      />
    </Grid>
  </StackPanel>
```

The problem with this is we want to be able to do this multiple times and not worry about leaving off a binding. So my question is there any way of doing this generically, preferably in a style. Another requirement is that it has to be in xaml not code behind.

So my ideal answer would be a style so I could the following in my xaml.

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <GroupBox Style="ChildrenVisibilityStyle">
        <GroupBox.Header>
        <Label Content="GroupBox"/>
      </GroupBox.Header>
      <StackPanel>
        <Label 
          Content="A"
          Visibility="{Binding Path=a_visible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}"
        />
        <Label 
          Content="B"
          Visibility="{Binding Path=b_visible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}"
        />
      </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <CheckBox 
        Content="A Visible"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.Row="1"
        IsChecked="{Binding Path=a_visible, Mode=TwoWay}"
      />
      <CheckBox 
        Content="B Visible"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        IsChecked="{Binding Path=b_visible, Mode=TwoWay}"
      />
    </Grid>
  </StackPanel>
```

I have looked at these questions and they lead me to think that this isn't possible; [binding in controltemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046262/wpf-binding-to-observablecollection-in-controltemplate-is-not-updated), [stackpanel visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569144/bind-stackpanel-visibility-to-the-visibility-property-of-its-children), [border visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921969/how-can-i-bind-a-border-visibility-to-the-visibility-of-containing-children-obje).

Sorry if this has been answered before. Thanks in advance for any answers/comments.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `MultiDataTrigger` to collapse the `GroupBox` when the Children are collapsed

Here is a working example:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <GroupBox>
        <GroupBox.Header>
            <Label Content="GroupBox"/>
        </GroupBox.Header>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label x:Name="lbl_a" Content="A" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chk_a, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}"  />
            <Label x:Name="lbl_b" Content="B" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chk_b, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}"  />
        </StackPanel>
        <GroupBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="GroupBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=lbl_a}" Value="Collapsed" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=lbl_b}" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="GroupBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </GroupBox.Style>
    </GroupBox>

    <CheckBox x:Name="chk_a" Content="A Visible" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="chk_b" Content="B Visible" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  />

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: But then if I want to make another GroupBox or add another item won't I have to add the conditions each time? This would be the same problem as with the MultiBinding

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches, both with attached behaviors:
The first is to set an attached property on the parent GroupBox and in the OnPropertyChanged callback loop over all the children and add a binding to a multibinding which is then hooked to the GroupBox Visibility property.  The problem with this approach is that you will have to specify the type(s) of the child(ren) you want to include in the multibinding (because you need to find them to add them to the group that dictates the parent's state) - FindVisualChildren will need to be called with multiple generic types if you want to capture everything you'd like it to...easily done though:

```
public sealed class GroupBoxCloseBehavior : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(GroupBoxCloseBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsEnabledChanged));

    public static bool GetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnIsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        GroupBox parent = obj as GroupBox;
        if (parent == null)
        {
            return;//Do nothing, or throw an exception depending on your preference
        }

        if (parent.IsLoaded)
        {

            MultiBinding mb = new MultiBinding();
            mb.Converter = new MultiVisibilityToVisibilityConverter();
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                foreach (CheckBox child in FindVisualChildren<CheckBox>(parent))
                {
                    mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Visibility") { Mode = BindingMode.OneWay, Source = child });
                }
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(parent, UIElement.VisibilityProperty, mb);
            }
            else
            {
                BindingOperations.ClearBinding(parent, UIElement.VisibilityProperty);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            parent.Loaded += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                MultiBinding mb = new MultiBinding();
                mb.Converter = new MultiVisibilityToVisibilityConverter();
                if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                {
                    foreach (CheckBox child in FindVisualChildren<CheckBox>(parent))
                    {
                        mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Visibility") { Mode = BindingMode.OneWay, Source = child });
                    }
                    BindingOperations.SetBinding(parent, UIElement.VisibilityProperty, mb);
                }
                else
                {
                    BindingOperations.ClearBinding(parent, UIElement.VisibilityProperty);
                }
            };
        }
    }

    private sealed class MultiVisibilityToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return values.OfType<Visibility>().Any(vis => vis != Visibility.Collapsed) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

<StackPanel>
    <GroupBox Header="GroupBox" cl2:GroupBoxCloseBehavior.IsEnabled="True">
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox x:Name="CheckOne" Content="CheckBox One"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="CheckTwo" Content="CheckBox Two"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Hide One" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button Content="Hide Two" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Doing this the other way, putting an attached property on the child elements and the OnPropertyChanged walking up the tree looking for a parent GroupBox might be better but you have the hassle of not knowing how many elements there are.  This is just a limitation of the binding.  At least with the GroupBox attached property you can construct the binding you need.